# Diff-in-Diff estimation in R where all IDs are treated but at different points in time

Tags: r, panel-data

I am trying to run a diff-in-diff on a dataset at the person-day level, where *all* individuals in the dataset are treated, albeit at different points in time.  There are 5 treatment dates, so, for instance, person X receives the treatment on day 1, person Y receives the treatment on day 10, person Z on day 5, and so forth.  What's important here is that every person is treated eventually.  Here's a stylized visual representation of the data (where LHS is the dependent variable):

[image]

Now, what I am trying to do is run a diff-in-diff where I compare person Z that was treated on day 5 with person Y that was not yet treated on day 5 (so, in this setup, person Y would serve as the control group).  This criteria would have to be extended to all the individuals in the sample so as to run a diff-in-diff simultaneously for all people.

I am not sure how to code this up in R.  I am pretty familiar with the `feols` function in R as I have used it several times in the past to run conventional diff-in-diffs such as the one illustrated here: https://lost-stats.github.io/Model_Estimation/Research_Design/event_study.html.  However, in this particular case, I am not sure what I should be interacting `Days_To_Treatment` with since if I interact with `Treatment` every observation prior to `Days_To_Treatment = 0` will be dropped.

I am honestly pretty clueless as to how to approach this at the moment.  Any help, advice, or tip would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It will be easier for people to help if you can share some example data in your question in the form of code people can run without manually retyping from a picture, and any code you've tried so far. It's often easiest to share data using the `dput` function, which takes a data object and produces a code recipe to recreate its structure and values. `dput(head(YOUR_TABLE, 14))` would do this for the first 14 rows of your data.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Jon!  Unfortunately, I am not allowed to share the data nor the code, otherwise I would have happily done so.

Comment: You did share the data in Image form and Jon is just requesting you to instead share the same data you share above but now in text format. Notice also that this question is best suitade for the cross validated site and not on stackoverflow\